# Django trying to save object with existing primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Today something strange happened. I'm importing data from a payment gateway after request:

```
for signature in response.json:
    Signature.objects.get_or_create(**signature)
```

json example:

```
[
  {'id': 1, 'plan': 1, 'customer': 1},
  {'id': 31, 'plan': 12, 'customer': 22}
  {'id': 2, 'plan': 3, 'customer': 50},
  {'id': 3111, 'plan': 12, 'customer': 22},
  {'id': 222, 'plan': 12, 'customer': 22},
]
```

Yes, my client didn't follow an ID sequence registering signatures manually on payment service so, I'm importing and keeping the same pk.

This code works as expected and data is now synced with payment service (all objects imported).

Now the strange behavior:

I'm using Django Rest Framework and after a POST (check validated_data) in my API the following error raises at this line:

```
Signature.object.create(**self.validated_data)
```

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "plans_signature_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists.

validated data:

```
{
   "plan": "3", # This is a foreign key to plan 3
   "payer_only": False,
   "schedule": "09:00",
   "payment_method: "CREDIT_CARD"
}
```

There is no 'pk': 1 or 'id': 1 in validated data

Django is trying to create an object with an existing key?

Debugging code, I called the Subscription.create() line 31 times then:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "plans_signature_pkey"
> DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists.

....

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "plans_signature_pkey"
> DETAIL: Key (id)=(31) already exists.

On call 32 this works. So, am I missing something? This looks a weird behavior to me.

Comment: Looks like you resetted the sequence in the database. Likely if you try to create elements in the database, it will not (immediately) work either, until the sequence has been updated that many times to generate new pk's.

Comment: It would be something related to the sequence in your database. I think it would be helpful if you provide with this aditional info: your database setup, your full stack of models, serializers and views related to the object having the problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and AliAsgari, Indeed. I'm trying to keep the same pk from payment service because operations relies on it. Any suggestion? Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long research I've found the solution.
I'm using POSTGRES and Django uses PostgreSQL’s SERIAL data type to store auto-increment keys. A manual primary key assign stops the pk auto-increment.
The solution: [sqlsequencereset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset)

```
$ django-admin sqlsequencereset app_label
```

"Use this command to generate SQL which will fix cases where a sequence is out of sync with its automatically incremented field data."